# How to set background to TextBox which is loaded in display mode of ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I found some of the website having solution to  edit style for ComboBox popup . Please suggest to customize background for textbox when the value selected from dropdown of combobox . Please find the below codes snippet ,

```
  <ComboBox  IsEditable="False"  x:Name="combo"  Background="Red"   SelectionChanged="combo_SelectionChanged"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Record.Data.ComboItems, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding CellBoundValue}" >                
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">Red</SolidColorBrush>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Please Share Your code..

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a "suggestion" site. You need to come here with a specific problem that you've encountered, show your code, let us know what is going wrong, along with what you want it to do, and we can then help you to fix your code. So, have a go at doing what you want and then come back if you get stuck and ask a question then.

Comment: Your question is not clear? And even no one can make out from your `xaml` what you exactly want to do. So please specify your problem clearly and provide proper code reference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set the background property of a TextBox based on the selection of a ComboBox:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ComboBox Width="100" Height="25" Name="MyComboBox">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Red" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Blue" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Green" />
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="100" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyComboBox,Path=Text}" Background="{Binding ElementName=MyComboBox,Path=Text}" />
</StackPanel>
```